# quiero que este programa me vuelva a pedir una contraseña cada vez que la que acabo de ingresar, incumpla las condiciones dadas

Tags: java, array, poo, matrices, contraseña

esta es una clase de mi programa:

```
public class CheckPsw {
    public String check(String psw) {
        char secuencia[][] = {{'1','2','3','4','5'},
                              {'a','b','c','d','e'}};
    
        char vecPsw[] = psw.toCharArray();
        int ei,ek,ej;

        if(psw.length() < 10 || psw.length() > 16)
            return "rango no disponible";

        for(ej = 0; ej < vecPsw.length - 1; ej++) { 
            for(ei = 0; ei < 4; ei++) {
                if(vecPsw[ej] == secuencia[1][ei]) { //si el vector comienza por una letra
                    for(ek = 0; ek < 5; ek++) {
                        if (vecPsw[ej+1] == secuencia[0][ek])//si le sigue un numero
                            break;
                    }

                    if(ek >= 5) return "secuencia no valida";
                } else if(vecPsw[ej] == secuencia[0][ei]) { //si el vector comienza por un numero
                    for(ek = 0; ek < 5; ek++) {
                        if (vecPsw[ej+1] == secuencia[1][ek])//si le sigue una letra
                        break;
                    }

                    if(ek >= 5) return "secuencia no valida";
                }
            }
        }

        return "Contraseña valida";
    }
}
```

de forma resumida, lo que hace esta clase es evaluar una contraseña, y decirme si es valida o no, debe asegurarse de que haya alternancia entre letra y numero (una letra después de un numero o viceversa, todo depende de con que empieces, pero ese no es el problema), además el programa evalúa si la contraseña tiene un numero de caracteres mayor a 10 y menor que 16, si no cumple estos requisitos, entonces me deberia volver a soltar una input que me pida leer la contraseña de nuevo.

ahora bien, por si acaso, el metodo main del programa es este:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int opcion;
    opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese una opcion \n1.evaluar contraseña"
            + "\n2.salir"));

    switch(opcion) {
        case 1:
            String psw = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese contraseña:");
            CheckPsw value = new CheckPsw();
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, value.check(psw));

        case 2:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"proceso finalizado");
    }
}
```

Comment: ya intentaste ponerle un do while?

Comment: O un while. De todas formas, yo repasaría también tu mecanismo de verificación. ¿Porqué permite solo 5 dígitos distintos? ¿Qué pasa con los otros números? Además tú código quedaría más legible si empleas recursión o expresiones regulares para verificar la alternancia. Supongo que no te han enseñado esas cosas, pero podrías echarle un ojo a esto último de las expresiones regulares.

Comment: @Julian porque no utilizas una expresión regular (`regexp`)?? Aquí tienes un ejemplo de su uso : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3802192/regexp-java-for-password-validation

Answer (score 0):

Mi recomendación es que uses un do-while para que en caso de que no sea una respuesta satisfactoria repita el bucle quedando así el codigo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int opcion;
    String text;
    opcion = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese una opcion \n1.evaluar contraseña"
            + "\n2.salir"));

    switch(opcion) {
        case 1:
            do {
                String psw = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("ingrese contraseña:");
                CheckPsw value = new CheckPsw();
                text = value.check(psw);
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, text);
            }while(!"Contraseña valida".equals(text));

        case 2:
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"proceso finalizado");
    }
}
```